# Android - Send data using JSON and httpurlconnect

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to send data from accelerometer to mysql server (via php script). First of all I did it using DefaultHttpClient but I just could send limited data, I read that using HttpURLConnection I could send large data (my main concern), so I decided to change my code to use HttpURLConnection but I don't know where my JSONArray is placed. Can anyone help?

Old Code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/Android/vals.php");
......

JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
postjson.add(jsonx);
postjson.add(jsony);
postjson.add(jsonz);
....

 httppost.setHeader("json",jsonx.toString());
 httppost.setHeader("jsony",jsony.toString());
 httppost.setHeader("jsonz",jsonz.toString());
 httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

New code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput (true);
                connection.setDoOutput (true);
                connection.setUseCaches (false);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf8");
                connection.connect();
```

I don't know where I should set my JSONArray data as I did in the code below. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Finally I achieved it by using DefaultHttpClient, but instead of sending my JSONArray through headers I did what follows:

```
        String jsonx = new Gson().toJson(param[0]); //This is inside asynctask
        String jsony = new Gson().toJson(param[1]);
        String jsonz = new Gson().toJson(param[2]);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.5/Android/va.php");
         try
         {
               ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> localArrayList = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair(); 
                localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",jsonx.toString()));
                localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsony",jsony.toString()));
                localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonz",jsonz.toString()));
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(localArrayList));
                    String str = EntityUtils.toString(httpclient.execute(httppost).getEntity());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I just post it if somebody has a similar trouble and I can help in somehow.

Answer (score 0):

http request using android

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url.com/file.php?a=abc&b=123&c=123");

            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                System.out.println("new respos "
                        + statusLine.getStatusCode() + " "
                        + statusLine.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// process execption }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

php code

```
 <?php
    $a= $_GET['a'];
    $b= $_GET['b'];
    $c= $_GET['c'];     
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am interested in HttpURLConnection and send a JSONArray through that.